# securityContext.privileged: Forbidden: disallowed by cluster policy

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, kube-apiserver, security-context

I can't start pod which requires privileged security context.
PodSecurityPolicy:

```
apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
kind: PodSecurityPolicy
metadata:
  name: pod-security-policy
spec:
  privileged: true
  allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
  readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
  allowedCapabilities:
  - '*'
  allowedProcMountTypes:
  - '*'
  allowedUnsafeSysctls:
  - '*'
  volumes:
  - '*'
  hostPorts:
  - min: 0
    max: 65535
  hostIPC: true
  hostPID: true
  hostNetwork: true
  runAsUser:
    rule: 'RunAsAny'
  seLinux:
    rule: 'RunAsAny'
  supplementalGroups:
    rule: 'RunAsAny'
  fsGroup:
    rule: 'RunAsAny'
```

ClusterRole:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: privileged
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - '*'
  resourceNames:
  - pod-security-policy
  resources:
  - '*'
  verbs:  
  - '*'
```

ClusterRoleBinding:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: privileged-role-binding
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: privileged
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
subjects:
# Authorize specific service accounts:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default 
  namespace: kube-system
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default 
  namespace: default 
- kind: Group
#  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  name: system:authenticated
# Authorize specific users (not recommended):
- kind: User
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  name: admin
```

```
$ k auth can-i use psp/pod-security-policy
Warning: resource 'podsecuritypolicies' is not namespace scoped in group 'extensions'
yes
$ k apply -f daemonset.yml 
The DaemonSet "daemonset" is invalid: spec.template.spec.containers[0].securityContext.privileged: Forbidden: disallowed by cluster policy
```

Not sure if it is needed but I have added PodSecurityContext to args/kube-apiserver `--enable-admission-plugins`

Any advice and insight is appreciated.  WTF is this: "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." !?!

Answer (score 6):

Just checked your Pod Security [Policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/) configuration on my current environment:

```
kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.1"
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.1"
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.1"
```

I assume that you've included Privileged [securityContext](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/) in the current DaemonSet manifest file.

```
securityContext:
  privileged: true
```

In order to allow Kubernetes API spawning [Privileged](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#privileged) containers you might have to set [kube-apiserver](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/) flag `--allow-privileged` to `true` value.

`--allow-privileged=true`

Therefore, I'm facing the same issue in my k8s cluster, once I disallow to run privileged containers with `false` option.

Comment: `--allow-privileged` is deprecated.

Comment: yep, this flag removed from `kubelet` config, but it still remains in `kube-apiserver`.